# Sending an email using batch command on getting an error

Tags: email, batch-file

I am trying to shoot an email if a command gives an error in a batch file. I am checking for non zero return code and then within an if statement trying to add the command to send the mail. Heres the code-

```
set errorlevel=
set OUTPUT_PATH= c:/personal/testWork/
call generate -project "HelloWorld" -output %OUTPUT_PATH%
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
@echo There is an error.
START mailto:somsuvra.sarkar@abc.com?subject=Test%%20message
@echo Error Message sent
)
```

In the log file am getting the message "Error Message Sent" but not receiving any emails. what is going wrong?

Comment: I think this works only if you have installed outlook. Beter try with blat.exe or powershell

Comment: `START mailto:somsuvra.sarkar@abc.com?subject=Test%%20message` <--- Open a cmd prompt and paste this to see if it works:

Comment: When I use a START mailto:something all it does is open an email window with the subject and addressee filled in.  It doesn't send anything---that has to be done manually.  I'm using Outlook.

Comment: So is there any way to send the mail automatically?